# Synchronise Windows Live contacts

Tags: windows, contacts, windows-live-mail

How can I set my wife's laptop to synchronise with the same contacts list as mine? We have separate  Windows live accounts.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this to the Web Apps Stack Exchange - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I can't think of any solution, at least none that doesn't require writing macros or code. You want to share a contact list continually, without sharing the account.

A one-time merging of contacts is easy: just export the contact list of your wife's and import it into your own account (on live.com, go to Contacts, Manage, Import/Export); then vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might be able to do this using [**Windows Live Groups**](http://groups.live.com/), but it doesn't look like you can.

It's not syncing, but you can share them using [**Contails**](http://www.contails.com/help/faq/False,share.html).

[image: Contails]